# Get set of unique values after joining float64 and integer64

Tags: pandas, join, group-by, aggregate

I'm trying to group and aggregate a df composed of `object`, `float64` and `int64`

```
(example df)
Number    Day        Colour   City    ... 
123       Monday     Red      London  ...
234       Monday     Blue     Paris   ...
234       Wednesday  Yellow   Paris   ...
345       Tuesday    Green    Berlin  ...
```

produce a new df like this

```
Number    Day                Colour        City    ...
123       Monday             Red           London  ...
234       Monday, Wednesday  Blue, Yellow  Paris   ...
345       Tuesday            Green         Berlin  ...
```

I initially tried

`df.groupby('Number').agg(lambda s: ', '.join({*s}))`

However, `.join` does not handle `int64` and `float64` well and results in loss of columns.

`df = df.groupby('Number', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join([str(i) for i in x]))` solves the issue of joining `float64` and `int64` but results in this

```
Number    Day                Colour        City           ...
123       Monday             Red           London         ...
234       Monday, Wednesday  Blue, Yellow  Paris, Paris   ...
345       Tuesday            Green         Berlin         ...
```

Is there a way to get a set of unique values (`{*s}`) and join while dealing with floats and integers? What I don't want are duplicate strings where rows have been aggregated (i.e. Paris, Paris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `unique`

```
df.groupby('Number').agg(lambda s: ', '.join(s.unique().astype(str)))
```